# Only one marker displaying in Google Maps (javascript v3 API)?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am using jinja to template out through some flask data; the resulting template info is a list of db objects with lat & lng attributes.

the resulting (generated) html looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(30.245395,-97.800273),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);

      var seismic = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.362736, -118.5664773),
        map: map,
        title: seismic
      });

      var reimers = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(30.3337, -98.1222),
        map: map,
        title: reimers
      });

  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

yet only one marker displays (the latter) out of the two.

any ideas?

EDIT:
it is worth mentioning i am getting this error in my console:
    File "/Users/ianseyer/Documents/programming/geology/templates/map.html", line 24, in        top-level template code
        position: new google.maps.LatLng({{ result.lat|float }}, {{ result.lng|float }}),
    UndefinedError: 'None' has no attribute 'lat'

but the html generated is entirely accurate

Comment: if you remove `reimers` does `seismic` show up?

Comment: hmm. good idea. it does not; but the html is accurate?

Comment: Your code is fine. I pasted it into a test page and ran it. Both your markers appear exactly as expected. But you need to zoom out to see them! For exmaple, if you put the map in a DIV 800px wide by 400px high, and change your zoom to `zoom: 4,`, you'll see both markers when the map is first loaded. I don't get any errors in the console either. If you're getting errors, please post the *entire* HTML page, not just the JavaScript excerpt.

Comment: For example, here is your code with that adjustment in a working map: http://mg.to/test/map2.html

Comment: ha! thank you. the first pin was supposed to be in texas, not california!

now i feel stupid...but at least i don't have to rewrite code!

Comment: Sometimes it's the little things that get you, isn't it? :-)

Comment: And don't feel stupid! If I had a penny for every I've tripped up on something this silly in my own code, I'd be a rich man by now!